# Django background working

Tags: database, django

At what part of the django code the models.py is converting into equivalent sql database ( those table are created when we do syncdb ,right), anyone know at which part of the (background) django code  does those conversion?

Comment: Are you asking when and where the SQL is created when running `syncdb` for an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation of model definitions in the table SQL is handled by each of the DB backends but the bulk of the shared logic can be found in `django.db.backends.creation` in particular the `BaseDatabaseCreation.sql_create_model` method. Current source on Github https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/creation.py